# Efficiently inserting or updating in boost::unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, unordered-map

I have a `boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>`, and whenever I add a Key/Value pair to the map for which there already exists a previous Key in the map, I want the old value to be deleted and replaced with the new value.  Also, since my compiler and libraries support `emplace()`, I'd like to use that (assuming that it may eliminate the construction of a temporary).

What is the most efficient way to program this?  I'm finding the Boost doc a little hard to understand here.

My compiler is g++ 4.4.7 with `-std=g++0x`

Comment: wouldn't it just be `map.emplace("key", "value");`? since emplace() `insert`'s the pair by moving if it's already existing. in fact, this would also move the key, but that are just 2 move's.

Comment: @itwasntpete: I tried using emplace() but it didn't seem to replace an existing value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the optional insertion point hint (obtained by calling `find()` first):

```
iterator       insert(const_iterator hint, const value_type& obj);
```

In the case of `emplace`, it's not a same-named overload:

```
template <class... Args> iterator emplace_hint(const_iterator position, Args&&... args);
```

I got these signatures from the C++14 draft standard because that's what I have handy, but they should date back to Boost if it has `emplace`, and otherwise you should update your compiler anyway. There's no sense in using such a shaky platform as Boost with `-std=c++0x` on an old compiler.

---

### Caveat

If you *aren't* replacing a preexisting entry, `find` will not return a useful hint.

If you *are* replacing an entry, you might as well just assign the new value to the existing object.

So, the hint is only useful in the case you actually want to `erase` the old object and `insert` a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to use `operator[]` here. Stuff like `emplace` and `insert` won't overwrite the value for you if it's already there, so just:

```
map[key] = newVal;
```

Works regardless of whether `key` existed in the map before or not.

Comment: I think you're right.  I was hoping to avoid the extra constructor call that some implementations of operator=() incur, but I'll go back to studying the copy-and-swap idiom; maybe that will do it.